# Unity fog glitch on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, fog

I'm following a tutorial by Brackeys, and i did everything correctly, and on the Editor, everything works like charm,

But when i build it for android, some weird bug/glitch pops up.

The bug in phone build, is that the scaled Cube i'm using as plane ( tried plane, same problem ) gradually changes color, and becomes same as the color of Camera background.
I'll add pictures of Camera and Lighting settings.

I'm using fog mode : Exponential Squared, and it works best to show what i want, on phone this mode bugs.

i tried other mode : Exponential and Linear, the bug didn't show, but so didn't the desired effect.

Here are two videos of comparaison :

Editor : 
https://youtu.be/gRIcu2Ubqd4

Phone :
https://youtu.be/UW8v49SGjOs

Comment: Lighting Settings :
https://s12.postimg.org/ptlonkxgt/lighting_Sets.png

Camera Settings : 
https://s12.postimg.org/dqgd00mel/cam_Sets.png

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem and I solved it changing the fog mode.

Go to `Window > Lighting > Settings` and at the bottom change the `Fog Mode to Exponential`:

[image: Fog Settings]

This is a weird bug that doesn't happens on editor or PC build but happens in android builds... I also figured out that the size of the ground is related to the issue, if you change to a smaller z scale (instead of 10.000 change to 1000) the bug will not occurs.

I hope it works for you!